# Output of split is not what I was expecting

Tags: python, list, split, file-io, python-re

I'm just learning python, and I'm having some problems reading a .txt file that I created.
**My objective:**
I have a txt file with a list of strings. I'm trying to read, process it and save every letter into a new list.

---

**example2.txt file:**
`[one, two, THREE, one, two, ten, eight,cat, dog, bird, fish] [Alonso, Alicia, Bob, Lynn] , [red, blue, green, pink, cyan]`

---

**My output**
['one, two, THREE, one, two, ten, eight, cat, dog, bird, fish]\n']
['Alonso, Alicia, Bob, Lynn], [red, blue, green, pink, cyan']

What I was expecting was something like this:
`['one','two','THREE','one','two','ten','eight','cat','dog','bird','fish','Alonso','Alicia','Bob','Lynn','red','blue','green','pink','cyan']`

**My code in python**
This is what I tried; you can ignore the comments

```
import re
# Creating a variable to store later the contents of the file
list_String = []
# Reading the file
file = open("D:\dir\example2", "r")

for line in file:
    print(re.split('^[\s].', line.strip(' ][')))
    #list_String.append(line.strip('[]').strip("\n").split(","))
    #list_String = re.split(r'[^\S\t.]', line)
    #print(line.split(r"\S"))
    #print(line)

#print(list_String)

file.close()
```

I also was reading the documentation on how to use **[re](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html)**, but I don't know if it is just me or is hard to understand.

I tried experimenting with what I read, but I'm still not getting what I wanted.

I even try this:

```
print(line.strip('][').strip('\n').strip(']').split(","))
```

**Output**

```
['one', ' two', ' THREE', ' one', ' two', ' ten', ' eight', 'cat', ' dog', ' bird', ' fish']
['Alonso', ' Alicia', ' Bob', ' Lynn] ', ' [red', ' blue', ' green', ' pink', ' cyan']
```

As you can see, it kind of works. However, between Lynn and red, the braces and the comma do not disappear somehow.

Thank you for the time and help

Comment: Don't worry , `re` is indeed hard to understand.

Comment: If you `re.split('[\[\], \n]+',line)` you need to discard initial and final empty strings but otherwise seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just find that doing an `re.findall` on the pattern `\w+` works here:

```py
inp = "[one, two, THREE, one, two, ten, eight,cat, dog, bird, fish] [Alonso, Alicia, Bob, Lynn] , [red, blue, green, pink, cyan]"
words = re.findall(r'\w+', inp)
print(words)
```

This prints:

```
['one', 'two', 'THREE', 'one', 'two', 'ten', 'eight', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish',
 'Alonso', 'Alicia', 'Bob', 'Lynn', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'cyan']
```

Comment: Hopefully no numbers or symbols in the set, but works well on this data.